# waiting until thread to finish before run next step

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have code that does multi-threading and I want to wait until the second thread finishes, after which I want to execute the next step, but my code is not waiting for the thread to finish. My code:

```
typing("hello world")
'I want to wait until this thread finishes,
'then continue executing the next MsgBox step.
MsgBox("hello")

Function typing(k As String)
    Dim th As New Thread(DirectCast(Function() runs(k), ThreadStart))
    th.IsBackground = True
    th.Start()
End Function

Function runs(ByVal k As String)
    For q As Integer = 0 To k.Length - 1
        Dim ss As String = k.Substring(q, 1)
        If Convert.ToChar(ss) >= "a" And Convert.ToChar(ss) <= "z" Then
            keybd_event(&H15, MapVirtualKey(&H15, 0), 0, 0) ' 
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Look into `Async` and `Await`... IMO use tasks which will queue up the threads wrapped in task objects that you can await.

Comment: You need to add synchonisation. But why is parallelism needed here anyway? You want to keep ui thread free? Threads are too expensive for this. Use a Task instead.

Comment: would you please some more specific example about Asnc or await? i'm new to threading. thanks!

Comment: [VB.NET Async Await](https://www.google.com/search?q=VB.NET+Async+Await)

Comment: thanks ! this is greatly help me! but i found very simple solution  while th.isAlive thread.sleep(100)  end while

Comment: Dont sleep the thread when there is work going on, it will block the process. Use tasks to handle this, you will find it more useful for this situation.